# How to improve disk space usage?

Tags: disk-usage

I am running my comp on Ubuntu 16.04
If I go for

```
du . | sort -nr | head -n10
```

to see the disk usage,then I was surprised to see

```
78015992    .
41469944    ./vmware
16427580    ./VirtualBox VMs
16296420    ./vmware/Windows 10 x64 (4)
12000828    ./VirtualBox VMs/mm2
8391256 ./vmware/Windows 10 x64
8391248 ./vmware/Windows 10 x64 (2)
8391016 ./vmware/Windows 10 x64 (3)
5664908 ./win
5664904 ./win/Windows 10 Pro VL X64 Build 14393.222 MULTi-7 v2 Sep 2016 {Gen2}
```

I have used puppet with vagrant,for study purposes.I did not know that working with virtual machines is space demanding.How to solve these issues?I want more free space on my SDD.

Comment: Remove unused VMs?

Comment: @AndyDalton How to remove from command line,just rm ./vmware/Windows 10 x64?

Comment: To avoid VM management issues  do not remove VMs from rm ... use your hypervisor  tools to stop & undefine them first , delete it from hypervisor tools if any else  rm the unused VM.  I you use vagrant I guess you use  virtual box in addition to vmware ?

Comment: @francoisP Yes,actually Virtual Box is sufficient for me.

Comment: ok so for virtualbox VMs, you can just rm the datafiles after the vm is stopped & delete the vm from the virtualbox  VM list (in GUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To free space, remove the Vagrant machines you do not need.

List them with

```
vagrant global-status --prune
```

then delete them with

```
vagrant box remove <vm-name>
```